# How to route multi subdomain with zend router hostname

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

I need to create routing in Zend to simply copy the current live site url structure which is sadly inconsistent

What i want to do is to route subdomain as follow:

www.site.com -> static router

a.site.com & b.site.com -> category controller

c.site.com & d.site.com -> location controller

the rest sub domain -> user controller

could anyone guide me how to solve this, thanks.

UPDATE:

First thanks Fge, vote your answer, it works but i need some more advice:

1. Since i have many subdomains for each rules is there a better way than add the rules in looping

   foreach($subdomains as $a){
    $tr = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
       "$a.site.com",
       array(
          'module'  => 'mod',
          'controller' => 'ctrl',
          'param_1' => $a
       ));
    $router->addRoute($a,$tr); 
   }
2. How to combine it with other routing type to parse the parameters (chained?), something like http://a.site.com/:b/:c, i want t parse it to param_1 (a), param_2 (b), param_2 (c)

Comment: sorry, seems the code formatted didnt work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note: Reverse Matching**
>   Routes are
>   matched in reverse order so make sure
>   your most generic routes are defined
>   first.

[(Zend_Controller_Router)](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Thus you have to define the route for all other subdomains first, then the specific ones:

```
$user = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':subdomain.site.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'user'
    )
);
$location1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'c.site.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'location'
    )
);
$location1 = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'd.site.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'location'
    )
);
// other definitions with known subdomain
$router->addRoute($user);   // most general one added first
$router->addRoute($location1);
$router->addRoute($location2);
// add all other subdomains
```

**Update for the updated question:**
1) This really depends on how different the parameters are you want to route a subdomain to. In your example you routed them all to the same model and controller and added the actual subdomain as a parameter. This can be done easily with the user-route i posted above. There the subdomain is set as parameter subdomain (`$request->getParam("subdomain")`). If you want the subdomains to be the action of a known controller/model you could replace `:subdomain` with `:action`. But as soon as you have other controllers/models for each subdomain, I'm affraid you have to loop over them (or use a config file).  For the example you provided in the question, the route simply could look like this:

```
$user = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    ':param1.site.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'user'
    )
);
// routes "subdomain".site.com to defaultModul/userController/indexAction with additional parameter param1 => subdomain.
```

As long as you don't have any schema in your subdomains it's very difficult to route them in a general way.

2) That's an example where [router chains](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.chain) come into play. The outer route would be the hostname route which handles the subdomain and the inner route would handle the `:a/:b` part. This could look like this for example:

```
$user->chain(new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':a/:b'));
```

Comment: thanks, it works, voted your answer but please have a look at my update above.